# Intermediate code generation and three address code

Tags: compilers

I have a Compiler Design course this semester but unfortunately the professor teaching this course have some issues with text book which is `Compilers, Principles, Techniques & Tools` by `Alfred Aho` and others.
For the section `Intermediate Code Generation` there is a slide which introduce a method to do so. I provide a photo here, the top is some definitions and the bottom is an example of the method which has no clear algorithm in the slide or even on the web:

[image: Intermediate Code Generation]

I've searched for the method for hours but not a single PDF or Youtube video were found.
Does anybody know anything about this method? What are the steps? What are these Semantic Stack and others?
Here is the link for slide for clearance:
[Full Slide](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9tU8COFYFccYTIwTXczeFJlZlk)

Comment: If you don't understand your professor's slides, why not ask them about it?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Sorry, I refused the edit. Please merge the account. The post does not need the "Edit:" tag inside, and besides that I think that the description about the professor takes too much space. I understand your frustration and the craving for knowledge, but any future users reading your question will benefit nothing from reading that some teacher does something some way.